# Docker container cannot access network

Tags: ubuntu, docker, kubernetes

All my containers cannot access internet if run without '--net=host'.

### Environment

- distro: `Ubuntu 13.04`
- docker: `1.6.2`
- go: `go1.4.2`
- ufw: `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"`
- 2375 port: `2375/tcp ALLOW Anywhere`
- docker daemon:
  `docker -d -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --bip=172.17.42.1/16 -b docker0`
- docker0 interface: `docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN`

### Question

I can append `--net=host` manually, but kubernetes always runs the docker without it. So any dockers in pods cannot pull images. What's worse, the Guestbook example failed either with the error `connection refused`, even add `x.x.x.x redis-master` in `/etc/hosts` of slaves.

So is there a way to use host mode as docker daemon arg, or the kube arg?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using this docker version? The 1.9 one has a lot of network lib upgraded. You might want to give it a try, if possible.
By default, v. 1.9, the "bridge" seems to be the default value. Note that you can change the default value in the conf file of the Docker daemon.

Comment: @M.Auzias Thank you very much! Maybe there's not appropriate version of docker supported Ubuntu 13.04. Docker.com has officially removed relevent files but 14.04 and 12.04. I have to fetch the latest docker, 1.6.2 from PPA. And my server also provides other services, so I should upgrade packages as less as possible. btw, Ubuntu has really many "docker" packages, lxc-docker, docker.io, docker-egine...oh my....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes allows you to enable host networking on a per-pod basis. See the configuration for the [Kubernetes apiserver](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/fc6247152bab039705da08f9ec7d180454bc249b/cluster/saltbase/salt/kube-apiserver/kube-apiserver.manifest#L114) for an example of where in the yaml config you should specify `"hostNetwork": true`.

Comment: Thanks! I should try to follow your advice, but I've made a decision: upgrade to docker 1.7.0. This problem takes me for a long time. When I `sudo dpkg -i --force-confilcts --force-overwrite lxc-docker`, the full screen warnings tell me that conflict packages will be overwritten, I couldn't remember ever having so happy. ok, I'm insane:), fortunately, the problem solved.